# No block to display at block settings in any contributed theme

Tags: 8, blocks, emails

I am trying to use *Simplenews* module for newsletter, but there is no block to display at block setting in any contributed theme after enabling the module.

However it's show when I activate the core theme (Bartik).

My problem is if I use contributed theme, there is no block of *Simplenews* module for enable the block on the front-end (on the block setting page).

What should I do in order the block is displayed?

Comment: if i use contributed theme, there is no block of simplenews module for enable the block on front-end In block setting page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the *Block Layout* page at `/admin/structure/block`, then *Place a Block* in the selected region and select *Simplenews subscription*. Once saved, the block should be available.

<sup>Source: [Simplenews on Drupal 8 - subscription block](https://www.drupal.org/node/2759303).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it works. I think you have great knowledge of drupal. billions of thanks.